# Can optional parameters depend on mandatory ones?

Tags: python, parameters

In python you can't define such a function :

```py
def cutafter(aList, end=len(aList)-1):
    return aList[:end]
```

Because it says : `NameError: name 'aList' is not defined`

But you can easily défine:

```py
def cutafter(aList, end=None)
    if not(end):
        end=len(aList)-1
    return aList[:end]
```

which is a very general trick. That's exactly what *optionnal* means to me.

So why is it not a feature ?

Comment: Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called. So they can't depend on other parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument . Tangential but totally related to how function arguments are evaluated

Comment: @Barmar hence why I didn't flag as a dupe. I just think it's a good starting point to understand the behaviour of function signatures in general

Comment: @roganjosh I can't seem to find a good dup. All my search results are either about `arg=[]` (which are all then linked to the "least astonishment" canonical dup) or `arg=variable` (where `variable` is a global variable that they modify after definition).

Comment: @roganjosh Found it!

Comment: And found another one that tries exactly the same `end=len(previousarg)-1` default as this one.

Comment: This has been proposed in PEP 671: https://peps.python.org/pep-0671/. Note this example which is very similar to the one in your question: `def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=>len(a), *, key=None):` (The idea is that the `=>` operator would allow an argument to be evaluated in terms of other arguments.)

Comment: So we're close to a feature ?

Comment: Well. There's certainly a very long discussion about it... https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/UVOQEK7IRFSCBOH734T5GFJOEJXFCR6A/